# Parsing a list of single numbers and number ranges

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, interval

I have input of a string containing a single number (like: \$3\$) or a range (like: \$1-5\$). Sample input, all together, looks like: `"1-5,3,15-16"`, and sample output *for that input* looks like `"1,2,3,4,5,15"`. Output doesn't need to be sorted.

I built something to parse this, but it's ugly. How can I improve this?

```
from itertools import chain
def giveRange(numString:str):
    z=numString.split("-")
    if(len(z)==1):
        return [int(z[0])]
    elif(len(z)==2):
        return list(range(int(z[0]),int(z[1])+1))
    else:
        raise IndexError("TOO MANY VALS!")

def unpackNums(numString:str):
    rList=[]
    rList.extend(set(chain(*map(giveRange,numString.split(",")))))
    return rList
unpackNums("1-2,30-50,1-10")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Disclaimer:** I'm not a Python programmer!

---

Your code isn't that bad. It's readable enough for me to understand it. B+ for readability!

---

Currently, you have this function:

```
def giveRange(numString:str):
    z=numString.split("-")
    if(len(z)==1):
        return [int(z[0])]
    elif(len(z)==2):
        return list(range(int(z[0]),int(z[1])+1))
    else:
        raise IndexError("TOO MANY VALS!")
```

Why don't you simply store the length in a variable?

Like this:

```
length=len(z)
if(length==1):
    return [int(z[0])]
elif(length==2):
    return list(range(int(z[0]),int(z[1])+1))
else:
    raise IndexError("TOO MANY VALS!")
```

Now, you don't have to calculate the length twice, only once.

---

The name `z` is a really bad name. Better names would be `numbers`, `pieces` or something similar.

---

Looking at the definition of [`chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), it seems to accept any iterable, which a `range()` happens to be. So, you probably don't need that `list()`, leaving this:

```
return range(int(z[0]),int(z[1])+1)
```

---

On your function `unpackNums` instead of creating an empty [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), you could use the a set comprehension:

```
def unpackNums(numString:str):
    return {x for x in set(chain(*map(giveRange,numString.split(","))))}
```

---

If you notice any inaccuracies, please comment.

Answer (score 8):

Since the whole exercise is a string-transformation problem, I suggest performing it using a regex substitution.

```
import re

def expand_ranges(s):
    return re.sub(
        r'(\d+)-(\d+)',
        lambda match: ','.join(
            str(i) for i in range(
                int(match.group(1)),
                int(match.group(2)) + 1
            )   
        ),  
        s
    )
```

I think that `expand_ranges` would be a more descriptive name than `unpackNums`.

Comment: This solution does not remove duplicate values. An input of `"1-2,30-50,1-10"` will yield an output of `1,2,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`